# Why is jmp -2 an infinite loop (x86)

Tags: assembly, x86

I am studying for an exam tomorrow, and in one of the lecture slides the professor makes note that "jmp -2 is an infinite loop for short relative jmp" without really explaining why. So, why is it an infinite loop? Isn't it just moving two bytes backward?

Comment: It *is* moving two bytes backward, and that is what makes it an infinite loop (it is a 2-byte instruction, so 2 bytes back is back to itself)

Comment: Relative jumps are relative to the beginning of the instruction after the jmp. A relative short jmp is encoded as 2 bytes. So beginning of next instruction -2 is beginning of the relative short jmp and thus an infinite loop.